# Not booting after selecting operating system in grub menu

Tags: boot

Anyone help me please :( , my Elementary OS not booting after I selecting an operating system in grub list. After click enter to boot on elementary os, I just get a blank screen with nothing in long time. Before this, I had updated the system in the software center but because my laptop became slow so I restarted and became like this cannot boot anymore. Someone help me please :( my schoolwork is not done yet